# How to use “abhorrence” in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

How do I use the word *abhorrence* in a sentence?

In my case, this is to express my [extreme disgust](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/127337/74671) of the Java programming language  to a college. (no hate ^-^) I wrote it as:

> Is my abhorrence with Java ridiculous?

Comment: One feels abhorrence *toward* or *for* that which one abhors.

Comment: Where do people pronounce it with a "t" sound before the "s" sound? [əb-ˈhȯr-ənts]

Comment: I have never heard that pronunciation, @Centaurus, so it must not be part of my regional dialect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [***usage***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abhorrence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabhorrence%3B%2Cc0) of **abhorrence** has decreased steadily from the early 19th century. ***[Comparing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abhorrence%20of%2Cabhorrence%20for%2Cabhorrence%20at%2Cabhorrence%20toward&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabhorrence%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabhorrence%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabhorrence%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabhorrence%20toward%3B%2Cc0)*** usage with the prepositional pairings *of*, *for*, *toward* and *at* shows that *abhorrence of* was the dominant usage, trailing off steadily with the same curve as the general usage of the word, but remaining significantly more popular than the the other prepositional pairings with abhorrence.

[***Abhorrence***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/abhorrence) OED

> NOUN
>
> A feeling of repulsion; disgusted loathing:

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=abhorrence&searchmode=none) suggests root meaning *from* and even earlier "at" are already in the word:

> **abhorrent + ence**
>
> ***abhorrent***
>
> 1610s, "in a position or condition to recoil," usually with from;
>
> from Latin abhorentem (nominative abhorrens), present participle of
>   abhorrere; see abhor.
>
> Meaning "repugnant" is from 1650s.
>
> Earlier was abhorrable (late 15c.).
>
> ***[abhor](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=abhor&allowed_in_frame=0)*** (v.)
>
> mid-15c., from Latin abhorrere "shrink back from, have an aversion
>   for, shudder at," from ab- "away"
>
> (see ab-) + horrere "tremble at, shudder," literally "to bristle, be
>   shaggy,"
>
> from PIE *ghers- "start out, stand out, rise to a point, bristle" (see
>   horror).

The prefix *ab* already implies *at*, but *from* might capture the intuitive response to *hor(or*).

Interestingly the OP chose *disgust* as the synonym for **abhorrence**. Disgust remains significantly more [popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abhorrence%2Cdisgust&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabhorrence%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisgust%3B%2Cc0), and the preposition *with* was the second most popular pairing with disgust. Perhaps the prepositional confusion surrounding *abhorrence* reveals a mental conflation with its synonyms?

*Is my abhorrence **of** Java ridiculous?* uses the **most popular** pairing with abhorrence.

*Is my abhorrence **for** Java ridiculous?* is 10 times **less** popular.

*Abhorrence **toward*** is even less popular, but *with* is extremely rare.

It would probably be better to use one of the other four more common prepositions to express your abhorrence of Java.

Comment: Please don't use corpus stats like ngrams without at least glancing at actual examples in context. "abhorrence with" is used predominantly in the context of constructions like "abhorrence with which...", i.e. not abhorrence with + noun.

Comment: @user52889 I don't quite understand what you are saying. Do you have some evidence that ScotM is wrong that 'abhorrence of [anything]' is not the most frequent use of 'abhorrence'? ScotM should also provide some evidence for his claim.

Comment: Not at all, I see @ScotM has updated his answer since my reply. He initially also cited a Google ngram chart showing "abhorrence with" was a common ngram but the actual citations you got when you dug into the data didn't support his claim (since removed) that "abhorrence with" was a coherent collocation and not simply down to the frequency of an unrelated construction using "with". As the answer stands now, it looks fine, so I'll upvote.

Comment: @user52889 I repent in dust and ashes for my inept use of Ngrams. I was as shocked by the results, but didn't realize the limitations of that tool. Your recommendation was an important lesson for this greenhorn :)

Comment: @user52889 thanks for clarifying, it's a better answer now.